# XmlSerializer not using XmlRoot defined on class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I am trying to serialize a custom class to XML.  Here is the class:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("KVP")]
public class SerializableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
{

    public SerializableKeyValuePair()
    { }

    public SerializableKeyValuePair(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the code that attempts to serialize it:

```
    var xmlWriter = new StringWriter();
    Type[] extraTypes = new Type[1] { typeof(SerializableKeyValuePair<string, string>) };
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<SerializableKeyValuePair<string, string>>), extraTypes);
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, functions);
    xmlRet = xmlWriter.ToString();
```

And here is the actual result:

```
<ArrayOfSerializableKeyValuePairOfStringString>
    <SerializableKeyValuePairOfStringString>
        <Key>Min</Key>
        <Value>Min</Value>
    </SerializableKeyValuePairOfStringString>
    <SerializableKeyValuePairOfStringString>
        <Key>MinAvgMax</Key>
        <Value>MinAvgMax</Value>
    </SerializableKeyValuePairOfStringString>
</ArrayOfSerializableKeyValuePairOfStringString>
```

What I'd like to see is the following, but it doesn't seem to be using the XmlRoot I define.  Can anyone help me figure out how to get this XML structure?

```
<ArrayOfKVP>
    <KVP>
        <Key>Min</Key>
        <Value>Min</Value>
    </KVP>
    <KVP>
        <Key>MinAvgMax</Key>
        <Value>MinAvgMax</Value>
    </KVP>
</ArrayOfKVP>
```

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But `SerializableKeyValuePair` isn't the root, `List<SerializableKeyValuePair<string, string>>` is!

I think you're looking for [`XmlType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[XmlType("KVP")]
public class SerializableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
{
    //...
}
```

And if you want to change the element name for your list, you can provide an `XmlRootAttribute` when creating the serializer:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<SerializableKeyValuePair<string, string>>), 
    null, extraTypes, new XmlRootAttribute("ArrayOfKVP"), string.Empty);
```

As an aside, `Serializable` has nothing to do with `XmlSerializer`.  Unless you need it for some other purpose, it can be removed.

Comment: That was it!  I knew that wasn't my root, but documentation said I couldn't use XmlElement at the class level, and I misunderstood what XmlType was for.  Thank you for setting me straight!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try to select the array of KVP before serializztion

```
var xKVP = xDoc.Root.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name.LocalName.Equals("car"));

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableKeyValuePair<string, string>));
using (var reader = xKVP.CreateReader())
{
    var result = (SerializableKeyValuePair<string, string>) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    Console.WriteLine(result.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
}
```

Another way, you could create a wrapper for your array of KVP's

```
[XmlRoot("ArrayOfKVP")]    
class ArrayOfKVP
{
    public ArrayOfKVP() {}

    [XmlElement("KVP")]
    public List<Foo> KVPList {get; set;}
}

[Serializable()]
[XmlType("KVP")]
public class SerializableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
{

    public SerializableKeyValuePair()
    { }

    public SerializableKeyValuePair(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The first option is not feasible for me, and the second isn't a working example because the Array class would need to know the data types of the key & value.  I'd really like to use existing serialization technology but I don't understand why using XmlRoot isn't working at the very least for turning <SerializableKeyValuePair/> into <KVP/>.